# How to process html form data with kemal and crystal

Tags: sinatra, crystal-lang, kemal

I want to get user input in an html form and use the data to populate a database table. Sinatra returns the form data in a hash, params. Can I do this with Kemal and Crystal?

Please note, I am in the process of learning Crystal, so this may not even be possible yet.

Thanks in advance for all answers. Meanwhile, I'm still digging:)

Comment: I found this while looking through the Crystal docs. I can use env.params.body and assign to a variable name and use name["key'] to access the form data. Still looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Crystal, an [`HTTP::Handler`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/HTTP/Handler.html) receives an [`HTTP::Server::Context`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/HTTP/Server/Context.html) argument. Through this context, you can access the request and read the form data. The same also applies to Kemal, there is also a section in the guid: [HTTP Parameters](http://kemalcr.com/guide/#http-parameters)